# PHP Prepared Statements; Weired Result

Tags: php, mysql, email, prepared-statement, email-verification

I try to implement a newsletter function in PHP. When a user subscribes on our website, a verification e-mail gets send to them. If they have already subscribed, they get a message displayed like: "you have already subscribed" or "E-Mail already registered, but not verified. The e-mail was resent.

```
function new_member($email,$list_id)
{
  global $db;
  $san_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  if (filter_var($san_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
    $hash = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10, $cstrong);
    $qry = "SELECT COUNT(*),active,access_hash FROM ".MYSQL_PREFIX."mailing_list_member WHERE address = '?' AND list_id = ?";
    var_dump($qry);
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare($qry)) {
      $stmt->bind_param("si", $san_email, $list_id);
      $stmt->bind_result($count,$active,$db_hash);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();
    } else {
      echo "sendet query: <pre>".$qry."</pre>\n"."Antwort: ".$db->error;
    }

    if ($count==1) {
      if ($active==1){
        return "E-Mail-Addresse bereits angemeldet.";
      } else {
        send_verification_mail($san_email,$list_id,$db_hash);
        return "E-Mail-Addresse bereits angemeldet, allerdings noch nicht bestätigt. Bestätigungsmail wurde erneut gesendet.";
      }
    } else {
      $qry = "INSERT INTO ".MYSQL_PREFIX."mailing_list_member (address,list_id,access_hash) VALUES ('?',?,'?')";
      if ($stmt = $db->prepare($qry)) {
        var_dump($san_email);
        $stmt->bind_param("sis", $san_email, $list_id, $hash);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
        send_verification_mail($san_email,$list_id,$hash);
        return "Bestätigungsemail wurde erfolgreich an ".$san_email." gesendet.";
      } else {
        echo "sendet query: <pre>".$qry."</pre>\n"."Antwort: ".$db->error;
      }
    }
  } else {
    return "Keine gültige E-Mail-Addresse angegeben!";
  }
}
```

For testing purpose this function got called like this (with a ream mail in there):

```
echo new_member('mail@example.com',1);
```

If I do this, the mail gets sent to the right e-mail-address, but not inserted into the database. Even if the user is already in the database, the e-mail is sent.

Comment: Weired is weird

Comment: If it was me , I'd get rid of all PHP for now , and focus on the queries.

Comment: @kerbholz `MYSQL_PREFIX."mailing_list_member` is there, so when i am on the development site, it doesnt use the main table, so it uses `dev_mailing_list_member`

Comment: Yeah, my fault, misread your code, deleted my comment ;). Where is `$count` and `$active` set in your script? Got it, again, my fault, need more caffeine, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ?-Placeholder needs not to be in quotes and both prepared statements miss an execute command. The first one needs to be:

```
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(*),active,access_hash FROM ".MYSQL_PREFIX."mailing_list_member WHERE address = ? AND list_id = ?";
 if ($stmt = $db->prepare($qry)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("si", $san_email,$list_id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($count,$active,$db_hash);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
}
```

and the second one:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO ".MYSQL_PREFIX."mailing_list_member (address,list_id,access_hash) VALUES (?,?,?)";
 if ($stmt = $db->prepare($qry)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sis", $san_email, $list_id, $hash);
    $stmt->execute();       
    send_verification_mail($san_email,$list_id,$hash);
    $stmt->close();
    return "Bestätigungsemail wurde erfolgreich an ".$san_email." gesendet.";
  }
```

Comment: i thought $stmt->fetch is adequate. The quotes are debris from my debugging.